# Issue with a smart contract not collecting tokens in the contract

Tags: erc-20, contract-debugging, binance-smart-chain

So ive got a smart contract that i found from another ERC-20 network and now im trying to use it on binance smart chain and having an issue, The contract is a token that collects a certain amount of token from each buy/sell transaction and then stores it in the contract. once a certain amount has built up it should then sell the tokens for BNB and distribute between the marketing wallet etc. However the issue is that the contract isnt collecting any tokens as we can see each transaction is taking 0 tokens to the contract. If anyone could help me look into this id appreciate it wouldnt think it would be too much work as was working perfectly on a different network. thanks

[No tokens being collected link](https://testnet.bscscan.com/token/0x569e4db549eba4bdecc6e6143ac440766b782650?a=0x569e4db549eba4bdecc6e6143ac440766b782650)

[Contract code](https://pastebin.com/rCwcdfC9)

Comment: That's a lot of code to analyze. I doubt you'll find this kind of help here - you should only present the relevant part of the code, explain what you have tried to make it work, what should it do and why you think it doesn't work.